# How to format time in SAS

Tags: time, sas, format

I have a dataset with three columns : Start, Stop and Date

Observations in my Start and Stop are time type.

I have the following two values in my Start and Stop columns:

24:49:00 and 25:16:00

As there are both over 24 hours format.

I would like to convert those two values to the following:

24:49:00 to 00:49:00

and

25:16:00 to 01:16:00

How to do this in both SAS and proc sql ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to convert them?  Use the TIMEPART() function.

```
 start_day=datepart(start);
 start_time=timepart(start);
 format start_time tod8.;
```

Or do you just want to display them that way?

```
 format start stop tod8.;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom for your detailed explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Start/Stop time-24:00:00 like this:

```
data _null_;
   start='25:16:14't;
   point='24:00:00't;
   _start=start-point;
   put _start;
   format _start time8.;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

SAS Time and DateTime values use seconds as their fundamental unit.

Thus you can use either *modulus arithmetic* or `TIMEPART` function to extract the less than 24 hour part of a > 24 hour time value.

```
data have;
  start = '24:49:00't;
  stop  = '25:16:00't;

  start_remainder = mod(start, '24:00't);   * modulus arithmetic;
  stop_remainder  = mod(stop,  '24:00't);

  start_timepart  = timepart(start);        * TIMEPART function;
  stop_timepart   = timepart(stop);

  format start: stop: time10.;
run;
```

After the computation do not expect *start_remainder is less than stop_remainder* to be always true.